# JSON returns only one object

Tags: javascript, json

I'm working in Domo pulling users from an API. I'm trying to pull ALL users and included addition entries in the site aka custom fields. As of now, it's only pulling one user. Also, in the obj2 log, it's only returning one object. Since it's not returning all the objects, it's never getting ID 4 which is Department. It only outputs ID 11 which is a type of ID we use and stops.

I feel like I'm close...any pointers what I need to fix?

I'm extremely new to JavaScript, be kind!

```
if(metadata.report == 'User'){
DOMO.log('metadata.reportname: ' +  metadata.report);
var base_url = 'https://app.com/api/author/users/';
var res = httprequest.get(base_url);
//DOMO.log('res: ' + res);
var raw = JSON.parse(res);
datagrid.addColumn('id', datagrid.DATA_TYPE_STRING);
datagrid.addColumn('hris_id', datagrid.DATA_TYPE_STRING);
datagrid.addColumn('full_name', datagrid.DATA_TYPE_STRING);
datagrid.addColumn('first_name', datagrid.DATA_TYPE_STRING);
datagrid.addColumn('last_name', datagrid.DATA_TYPE_STRING);
datagrid.addColumn('department', datagrid.DATA_TYPE_STRING);

var users = raw.users;
//DOMO.log('users: ' + JSON.stringify(users));

for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
  var obj = users[i];
}
  //make new specific request with includes
  var temp = obj.id;
  var temp2 = '?includes[]=custom_fields';
  var uniq_url = base_url.concat(temp.concat(temp2));
  //DOMO.log(uniq_url);
  var res2 = httprequest.get(uniq_url);
  var raw2 = JSON.parse(res2);
  //DOMO.log((raw2));

  var linked = raw2.linked;
  var cf = linked.custom_fields;
  var cfv = linked.custom_field_values;

 for(var g = 0; g < cfv.length; j++){
    var obj2 = cfv[g];
    DOMO.log(obj2.value);
  }
    if (obj2.custom_fields.id == 4){ 
    DOMO.log("Department is: " + obj2.value);
    }

    //if (obj2.links.custom_field.id == 5){
      //DOMO.log('Position is ' + obj2.value);


  //DOMO.log('JSON ' + res);
  //DOMO.log('id: ' + obj.id);
  datagrid.addCell(obj.id);
  //DOMO.log('hris_id: ' + obj.hris_id);
  datagrid.addCell(obj.hris_id);   
  //DOMO.log('full_name: ' + obj.hris_id);
  datagrid.addCell(obj.full_name);          
  //DOMO.log('first_name: ' + obj.first_name);
  datagrid.addCell(obj.first_name);
  //DOMO.log('last_name: ' + obj.last_name)
  datagrid.addCell(obj.last_name);
  //DOMO.log('value: ' + obj.value);
  datagrid.addCell(obj.value);
  datagrid.endRow();
}  

//Console Log;
metadata.reportname: User
https://app.com/api/author/users/976?includes[]=custom_fields
{"id":"3785","value":"12870","links":{"custom_field":{"id":"11","type":"custom_fields"}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the for loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
  var obj = users[i];
}
```

You are iterating all users, but always taking the current [i] user.

I'm guessing that you meant that bracket will surround the entire code:

Like this:

```
var users = raw.users;
//DOMO.log('users: ' + JSON.stringify(users));
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  var obj = users[i];

  //make new specific request with includes
  var temp = obj.id;
  var temp2 = '?includes[]=custom_fields';
  var uniq_url = base_url.concat(temp.concat(temp2));
  //DOMO.log(uniq_url);
  var res2 = httprequest.get(uniq_url);
  var raw2 = JSON.parse(res2);
  //DOMO.log((raw2));

  var linked = raw2.linked;
  var cf = linked.custom_fields;
  var cfv = linked.custom_field_values;

  for (var g = 0; g < cfv.length; j++) {
    var obj2 = cfv[g];
    DOMO.log(obj2.value);
  }
  if (obj2.custom_fields.id == 4) {
    DOMO.log("Department is: " + obj2.value);
  }
}
```

Edit:
After your additional input, I see another mistake in the next for loop - same issue, you are iterating it but eventually taking one value (the last one) and there is a mistake because j is not defined, because you are using g.

Fixed code:

```
  if (metadata.report == 'User') {
    DOMO.log('metadata.reportname: ' + metadata.report);
    var base_url = 'https://app.com/api/author/users/';
    var res = httprequest.get(base_url);
    //DOMO.log('res: ' + res);
    var raw = JSON.parse(res);
    datagrid.addColumn('id', datagrid.DATA_TYPE_STRING);
    datagrid.addColumn('hris_id', datagrid.DATA_TYPE_STRING);
    datagrid.addColumn('full_name', datagrid.DATA_TYPE_STRING);
    datagrid.addColumn('first_name', datagrid.DATA_TYPE_STRING);
    datagrid.addColumn('last_name', datagrid.DATA_TYPE_STRING);
    datagrid.addColumn('department', datagrid.DATA_TYPE_STRING);

    var users = raw.users;
    //DOMO.log('users: ' + JSON.stringify(users));

    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
      var obj = users[i];
      //Move brackets to end

      //make new specific request with includes
      var temp = obj.id;
      var temp2 = '?includes[]=custom_fields';
      var uniq_url = base_url.concat(temp.concat(temp2));
      //DOMO.log(uniq_url);
      var res2 = httprequest.get(uniq_url);
      var raw2 = JSON.parse(res2);
      //DOMO.log((raw2));

      var linked = raw2.linked;
      var cf = linked.custom_fields;
      var cfv = linked.custom_field_values;

      //for (var g = 0; g < cfv.length; j++) { --> g++ instead of j++
      for (var g = 0; g < cfv.length; g++) {
        var obj2 = cfv[g];
        DOMO.log(obj2.value);
        //Move bracket to after using obj2
        //Added more conditions:
        if (obj2.custom_fields.id == 4 || obj2.custom_fields.id==5 || obj2.someOtherProp=="Something") {
          DOMO.log("Department is: " + obj2.value);
          //DOMO.log('JSON ' + res);
          //DOMO.log('id: ' + obj.id);
          datagrid.addCell(obj.id);
          //DOMO.log('hris_id: ' + obj.hris_id);
          datagrid.addCell(obj.hris_id);
          //DOMO.log('full_name: ' + obj.hris_id);
          datagrid.addCell(obj.full_name);
          //DOMO.log('first_name: ' + obj.first_name);
          datagrid.addCell(obj.first_name);
          //DOMO.log('last_name: ' + obj.last_name)
          datagrid.addCell(obj.last_name);
          //DOMO.log('value: ' + obj.value);
          datagrid.addCell(obj.value);
          datagrid.endRow();
        }
      }
      //if (obj2.links.custom_field.id == 5){
      //DOMO.log('Position is ' + obj2.value);

      //Moved this code inside the if id==4.

    }
  }
```

Comment: Interesting thought. I have tested pulling only the users and it works perfectly fine. Once I started at //make new specific request with includes, the code only started pulling one user. Do I need to change my for loop?

Comment: I added the rest of my code in the original post with the ending bracket that was already there. @Ziv

Comment: @computerguyinhere ok so just remove the ending bracket on line 5 :)

Comment: Alright, this is my fault, I didn't post the code above the for loop. It's all there now.  @Ziv

Comment: @computerguyinhere so you have to move the closing bracket of the for loop to the end. (from the line after var obj = users[i];)

Comment: So that seems to be working now. Thanks.

However, in my next for loop var obj2. 

When I have DOMO.log(obj2); - it's outputting correctly for what I want. 

As soon as I comment out this log, I get a console error;
Console: j is not defined

I've never seen that one before.

Comment: Figured out that j is not define because, there isn't a value assigned to this user.

I need to create something that says;
if (ob2.custom_fields.id == 4){
DOMO.log("Department is: " + obj2.value);

If not print NULL.

Comment: @computerguyinhere you have a mistake it should be g++ not j++, also same issue with second loop - see my edit

Comment: @computerguyinhere good. Please don't forget to mark as answer (check mark appears near answer) and g/l

Comment: Ok, It's now printing things out again and populating the department column with all the values. However, obj2.value isn't being defined correctly to ID 4. Thus just outputting any value that it hits first. How can we define our department value? The JSON format is in the original code towards the bottom. @Ziv

Comment: @computerguyinhere Not really sure what you mean, do you want to add to the grid only objects with department id = 4?

Comment: That is precisely my end goal here. I want the value of id 4 in the grid.

Comment: I modified the code. With your edit, I was able to print out department correctly. However, I did add  a new variable to handle custom_field_values.links. The 'if statements' are acting funny. It appears that only one if statement will work at a time. When I enable two if statements here, it won't run. Soon as I comment one out, it runs perfectly. Positions will post if department is commented out - vice versa.

Comment: @computerguyinhere what if are you trying to add? as the code now, it will only support 1 "if", you can add different conditions to this if by using the "or" syntax - || ie if (id==1 || id==2)

Comment: Just trying to add multiple ID's to the datagrid here. Would the or syntax define these?

Comment: @computerguyinhere see my edit - i've added a check for id =5 and some other random test

Comment: I've tried the or statement and now it's not looping through all the users, Weird. What did you want me to try for the last obj2.someOtherProp? I left that out as well and it still only does one user.

Comment: Strange though, if I only call for id==4 it will populate all users correctly for the department still. Domo is really picky in es5.